# VBA, EXCEL, WORD: Formatting of Horizontal line from Excel in Word Header

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, ms-word

From excel VBA I am adding a horizontal line to a header of a Word document.

```
Dim a As Word.Range
Set a = oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
a.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
a.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard
```

Next I want to format that line:

```
a.InlineShapes(1).Height = 1
```

But this throws and error *5941 - The requested member of the collection does not exist.*

I also tried

```
With a.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard 
    .Height = 1
End With
```

But didnt work either.

I tried the code in Word vba, which worked. Am I missing something here? How can I format the line from Excel?

**Edit**

I stopped the code after adding the line. Then I executed `.InlineShapes.Count`, which returned 0. Then I added a line in the document body and executed again, which return 1 then. So the problem seems to be that the header can not be access from Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, which uses an InlineShape object to "hold" the line you're adding so that you can address it directly. I can't figure out why what you have isn't working, but if this doesn't work it might at least give you a more informative error message:

```
Dim rng As word.Range
Dim ils As word.InlineShape

Set rng = oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
rng.Collpase Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
Set ils = rng.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard(rng)
ils.height = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim a As Object
Set a = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
With a.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
    .Range.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard.Height = 1
End With
```